# How to get slope of variables and intercept from a stored(serialized using python pickle) ML model

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Python code snippet which loads stored ml model and predicts with new inputs.

```
mlModel = pickle.load(open('linear_model4.pickle','rb'))
request_body = request.body.decode('utf-8')

parsed_request = makePredictionInput(json.loads(request_body))
rb=json.loads(request_body)
print(parsed_request)


result = mlModel.predict(parsed_request)
```

It uses 5 inputs for prediction.

Is there a way to get the slopes and intercept from above loaded model sothat i can form the equation
as

```
y = intercept + slope1*variable1+ slope2*variable2+ slope3*variable4+.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your model is a linear model given the equation you want to reconstruct. `mlModel.coef_` should be what you want. See [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#linear-models) for example.

`mlModel.intercept_` is the intercept.

`coef_` are in the same order as the training data. For example if `age` is the third column in your training data, the coefficient for age is the third element in `mlModel.coef_`.

In your case you are only making predictions, but I assume that you know the meaning of the columns in the data you are trying to predict on. This should be the same order as in your training data.

Comment: i got the co-efficent as [[ 0.07695749 -0.12990199  0.0078301   0.14021539 -0.71441821  0.96183299]]. How can i interpret which co-efficient match to which variable. ie what is the coeffienct for age.

Comment: I edited my message to clarify the coefficients order (also forgot to mention intercept)